# click on "plot view" for OpenMCT have a error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I was going through [Tutorial telemetry adapter](https://nasa.github.io/openmct/docs/tutorials/#telemetry-adapter)  for get start with Nasa OpenMCT mission control framework. at the end of step 4 right [step real time telemetry](https://nasa.github.io/openmct/docs/tutorials/#step-4-real-time-telemetry) base of tutorial picture i should have some Generators that can be shown in the plot view.
[image: tutorial picture]

But there is some problem.
I can get the telemetry data on my local openmct application and its look like that [image: picture].
but when i click on plot view there is nothing to show and here is [image: image errors].

this is the errors:

error1:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined
at constructor.onXKeyChange (PlotSeries.js:169)
at new constructor (PlotSeries.js:89)
at child.addTelemetryObject (SeriesCollection.js:89)
at child.initialize (SeriesCollection.js:48)
at child.Collection (Collection.js:44)
at new child (extend.js:40)
at child.initialize (PlotConfigurationModel.js:72)
at child.Model (Model.js:49)
at new child (extend.js:40)
at PlotController.getConfig (PlotController.js:135)
```

error2:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
at PlotController.destroy (PlotController.js:151)
at n.$broadcast (angular.js:16238)
at n.$destroy (angular.js:15850)
at destroyScope (TemplateLinker.js:100)
at populateElement (TemplateLinker.js:122)
at showTemplate (TemplateLinker.js:130)
at changeTemplate (TemplateLinker.js:162)
at Object.refresh [as fn] (MCTRepresentation.js:191)
at n.$digest (angular.js:15753)
at n.$apply (angular.js:16024)
```

error3:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined
at constructor.onXKeyChange (PlotSeries.js:169)
at new constructor (PlotSeries.js:89)
at child.addTelemetryObject (SeriesCollection.js:89)
at child.initialize (SeriesCollection.js:48)
at child.Collection (Collection.js:44)
at new child (extend.js:40)
at child.initialize (PlotConfigurationModel.js:72)
at child.Model (Model.js:49)
at new child (extend.js:40)
at PlotController.getConfig (PlotController.js:135)
```

so why these errors occur ?

Comment: What is your question? If that screencap shows some errors, they need to be in the question as text. Also, let's see the [mcve] that you are working with.

Comment: i edit my text , so do you catch the errors?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking, but those messages are telling you something is undefined or null. However, unless there is some code you can share, it is unclear how you would like us to help you. If you are just running someone's software and it is failing, you should bring it up with the vendor of that software. Show a [mcve] please.

Comment: Someone recently posted an answer here saying that the tutorial is out of date. That answer was deleted, but here's the link for the updated OpenMCT tutorial https://github.com/nasa/openmct-tutorial as well as a related issue and any further comments https://github.com/nasa/openmct/issues/2540